# Multiple multivariate regression problem - auto correlated dependent variables

Tags: least-squares, multivariate-regression, dependent-variable

I have a classic multivariate regression problem, i.e. dependent variables are stored in matrix $Y$ having dimension $n \times p$. So $p$ observations come from the same respondent $i$ and we need to expect correlated residuals. The explanatory variables are stored in $X$ and as standard in the multivariate regression model, each of the $p$ observations of respondent $i$ has the same common $X$. Say $Y_i$ holds the income of a guy at 5 points in time, and it shall be explained by his gender and his education only, then $X_i$ holds male and college as the explanatory variables for all of his $Y_i$. As an output of the regression one gets vectors $\beta_1,...,\beta_5$, one vector $\beta$ for each of the 5 points in time.

In my specific problem some of the $Y$ have been constructed in such a way that the correlation of their errors is 1. So for these I would not need 5 vectors $\beta_1,...,\beta_5$, but because of the prefect correlation a reduced form would already contain all information, like $\beta_1 = \beta\alpha_1$, $\beta_2=\beta\alpha_2$, ... Where each $\alpha$ is a scalar and not a vector.

I understand that the multivariate regression, i.e. estimating 5 vectors $\beta_1,...,\beta_5$, should give unbiased but inefficient results (true?). Nevertheless, does anyone of you have an idea how to estimate the model from above without the redundant $\beta$-vectors?

If I know that dependent variables are highly correlated by construction is it right to do multivariate regression or should I just perform separate OLS for each of the dependent variables? Or is there an alternative to this issue?